# Using same facebook pixel on landing page and purchase website

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

My facebook ad leads to a landing page, which is easy to track with the facebook pixel. But that landing page leads to another purchase page with a different domain. I was wondering how can I track the purchase page with the same pixel?

Theoretically I could create a new container with Google Tag Manager for the purchase website, and add facebook pixels tags there, but how would the pixel on the purchase page know that it was referred from the landing page? Because the purchase page is not reached directly from the facebook ad.

Just in case someone finds it confusing:
Facebook ad > Landing page > Purchase page (different domain)

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Facebook tag it doesn’t need to know it was referred, just add the conversion parameters on the purchase page and it should work fine as it just relates the purchase to the click on the ad not the path that was made. An example would be if the user clicks on the ad then leaves and comes back days later to purchase this would still trigger a conversion to the ad.